# How to remove duplicate item from list of maps with it's property in Flutter | Dart

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web

I have a list of Maps. The below is the list of maps,

```
 List teachers = [
    {
      'name':'John',
      'subject':'English'
    },
    {
      'name':'Rohan',
      'subject':'Hindi'
    },
     {
      'name':'Benny',
      'subject':'English'
    },
     {
      'name':'Rose',
      'subject':'Tamil'
    },
     {
      'name':'Shine',
      'subject':'Kannada'
    },
     {
      'name':'Tintu',
      'subject':'English'
    }
  ];
```

From this I want to keep any of the one english teacher and remove all other teacher with subject english.
The below is the expected result.

```
 List teachers = [
    {
      'name':'John',
      'subject':'English'
    },
    {
      'name':'Rohan',
      'subject':'Hindi'
    },
     {
      'name':'Rose',
      'subject':'Tamil'
    },
     {
      'name':'Shine',
      'subject':'Kannada'
    },
  ];
```

Comment: You'd use `List.removeWhere(predicateFunction)`. https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.18.3/dart-core/List-class.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use [collection](https://pub.dev/packages/collection/install) package and try this:

```
var grouped =
    groupBy(teachers, (Map<String, String> value) => value['subject']);

List<Map> result = grouped.entries.map((e) => e.value.first).toList();
print("result  =$result");//result  =[{name: John, subject: English}, {name: Rohan, subject: Hindi}, {name: Rose, subject: Tamil}, {name: Shine, subject: Kannada}]
```